# FlatList: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am getting this error when using Flatlist

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

How can I resolve this? I don't think there is some import or export mistake here

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
    {
      id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
      title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
      id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
      title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
      id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
      title: 'Third Item',
    },
  ];
  
  function Item({ title }) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

export default class Abc extends React.Component<{}, {}> {

    console.log("RENDER RENDER");
    render(): React.ReactNode {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={DATA}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.title} />}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      marginTop: 10,
    },
    item: {
      backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
      padding: 20,
      marginVertical: 8,
      marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 32,
    },
  });
```

Comment: It's working fine, after removing the `console.log()`.  Check this [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@techysharnav/277b69)

Comment: @TechySharnav still not working

Comment: Do you use class components for a reason? I advice you to use functional components, maybe refactoring the code would help.